# Vector Sum With Python

Tags: python, vector, sum

Write a function named `vectorSum(l1, l2)` that takes twolists of numbers and adds the numbers in l2 on l1, one by one.If l2 is shorter than l1, then l2 recycles from the beginningonce it is over. If l2 is longer than l1, then only the first partof l2 that matches the length of l1 is considered. Your functionmust return the summed up resulting list. For example,

vectorSum([1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3]) returns [2,4,6,5,7] because:Write a function named `vectorSum(l1, l2)` that takes two

lists of numbers and adds the numbers in l2 on l1, one by one.

If l2 is shorter than l1, then l2 recycles from the beginning

once it is over. If l2 is longer than l1, then only the first part

of l2 that matches the length of l1 is considered. Your function

must return the summed up resulting list. For example,

vectorSum([1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3]) returns [2,4,6,5,7] because:

1,2,3,4,5

+ + + + +

1,2,3,1,2    -> Here, l2 recycles from the beginning

= = = = =

2,4,6,5,7

vectorSum([1,2,3], [1,2,3,4,5]) returns [2,4,6] because:

1,2,3

+ + +

1,2,3,4,5    -> Here, only the first 3 items of l2 are used

= = =

2,4,6

vectorSum([1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,1,2,1]) returns [2,4,4,6,6]

1,2,3,4,5

You can assume that l1 and l2 are not empty.

vectorSum([1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3]) returns [2,4,6,5,7] because:

1,2,3,4,5

+

+

```
+ 

  + 

    +
```

1,2,3,1,2    -> Here, l2 recycles from the beginning
= = = = =
2,4,6,5,7

vectorSum([1,2,3], [1,2,3,4,5]) returns [2,4,6] because:

1,2,3

+

+

```
+
```

1,2,3,4,5    -> Here, only the first 3 items of l2 are used
= = =
2,4,6

vectorSum([1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,1,2,1]) returns [2,4,4,6,6] because:

1,2,3,4,5

+

+

```
+ 

  + 

    +
```

1,2,1,2,1    -> Here, length of l2 matches the length of l1
= = = = =
2,4,4,6,6

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please check out following links on how to ask a question that is more likely to get an answer.
[How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and
[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a list comprehension to iterate over the length of the first list, and using the remainder of the length of the first list divided by the length of the second list as the index for the second list, providing us effectively with a loop over the second list if that list is shorter than the first list.

len(l1) > len(l2)

```
>>> l1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> l2 = [1,2,3]
>>> [l1[i] + l2[i%len(l2)] for i in range(len(l1))]
[2, 4, 6, 5, 7]
```

len(l1) < len(l2)

```
>>> l1 = [1,2,3]     
>>> l2 = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> [l1[i] + l2[i%len(l2)] for i in range(len(l1))]
[2, 4, 6]
```

len(l1) == len(l2)

```
>>> l1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> l2 = [1,2,1,2,1]
>>> [l1[i] + l2[i%len(l2)] for i in range(len(l1))]
[2, 4, 4, 6, 6]
```